# Simple js framework, DOM. (module style, trying to make it like jQuery-style)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, frameworks

It's just a training exercise.
To solve this I've written such script using this  [material](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

```
    (function(window) {
    function smp(selector) {
    return new smpObj(selector);
    }

    function smpObj(selector) {
        this.length = 0;
        if (!selector ) {
            this.el = [];
            return this;
            }
        if (selector.nodeType ) {
            this.el = selector;
            this.length = 1;
            return this;
        } else if(selector[0]==='#'){
            this.el = document.getElementById(selector.slice(1, selector.length));
            this.length = 1;
            return this;
        } else if(selector[0]==='.'){
            this.el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.slice(1, selector.length));
            this.lenghth=this.el.length
            return this;
        }
        else return null;
    }
 })(window);
```

Then i try to call like this:

```
smp('body');
```

but browser can't find my smp definition.
In future i wanna add some methods to use it like this(for example, changing color):

```
 smp('.myClass').method('attr')
```

I'd appreciate, if someone can show me my mistake.

UPD:
Still have some problems with adding methods like:

```
  smp('.myClass').method('attr')
```

I've tried like this:

```
  (function color(smp) {
    window.smp.prototype.changeColor = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
            this.el[i].style.color = color;
        return this;
    };
})(smp);
```

Comment: `selector` is a string...  strings have no property `nodeType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Module Export` section in the article you linked to explains it.

In order to actually use the function you need to assign it to a variable, either global or local. You can do that locally by saying:

```
var smp = (...)(window)
```

But that means you have to return something in your function. So at the end of your code, before the `})(window)` return the `smp` function

```
return smpSelector
```

Putting it all together:

```
var smp = (function(window) {

    function smpSelector(selector) {
      // ... snip
    }

    function smpObj(selector) {
      // ... snip
    }

    return smpSelector;

 })(window);
```

Finally, if you want this in a separate file and still have access to `smp`, you can assign it globally. In fact this is what most libraries, including `jQuery` do:

```
(function(window) {

    function smpSelector(selector) {
      // ... snip
    }

    function smpObj(selector) {
      // ... snip
    }

    window.smp = smpSelector

 })(window);
```

Now from a different file we can do:

```
 <script src="/path/to/smp/file"></script>
 var foo = smp('something')
```

Comment: Wow, you answer helped a lot, especially latest edit(that the thing, i was aimed at at the very beginning).
Think i've understood now,
Really appreciate.

Comment: keep on coding my friend!

Comment: I have one more issue(with adding methods). Will be gratefull,if you can check it.

Comment: Would be happy to help, but I'd recommend creating a new question for it and only writing up the parts that are relevant for what you're doing now.